# how to remove all string after question mark in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a column of urls like `http://mydomain/app?u=asdfa&b=fnsn` with varying number of parameters. I would like to remove all the string after question mark onwards and get distict urls.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substring_index(url, '?', 1)
```

will return everything before the first ? or the entire url if there is no ?